# How to replace all values of column with null values in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a CSV file where:

- column1 has names
- column2 is age

For example:

```
column1, column2
Maria.,    24
Sunio.,    65
Morris.,   45
```

There 100 fields.

I want to replace column1 values with `NULL`:

Expected Output:

```
column1, column2
NULL,      24
NULL,      65
NULL,      45
```

How can I achieve this?

I have tried with update record....but not successful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

With update record processor you are able to update any column to any value you want.
Here is an example:
[[image]

You should consider there is no such thing as null  value in csv, if you want to treat some value as null you should specify that on CSVReader or CSVRecordSetWriter as follow:
[image]